# Pure Swift project. Which Apple APIs am I allowed to use?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, compatibility

Every since Apple started open-sourcing Swift last year, I have wondering about which frameworks are going to be distributed along with its standard library.

I'm working on a *pure Swift* project at the moment and need to use some common objects without compromising compatibility with other (POSIX) systems. Are these objects shipped in Swift's STL?

- (De)serialization objects: `NSCoder`, `NSKeyedArchiver`, `NSCoding`, `NSXMLParser`
- Concurrency objects: `NSOperationQueue`, `dispatch_async()`, `dispatch_sync()`
- File manipulation objects: `NSFileManager`, `NSURL`, `NSData`

And if not, are there any *pure Swift* alternatives?

Comment: what does pure Swift mean for you, did you even create a project all the classes are present in swift, as in Obj-C they're public

Comment: By *pure Swift* I mean the open-source implementation of Swift provided at http://swift.org (it has been unveiled few months ago). The reason I'm asking is that I've built a lot of iOS projects with Swift and Obj-C but none with open-source Swift, and I seriously doubt that Apple's going port all frameworks over to Linux.

Comment: I've not worked on Swift outside of Xcode and iOS/OS X but it looks like you need to take a look at the [CoreFoundation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation) framework, which does appear to have most if not all that you are asking about. See also [here](https://swift.org/core-libraries/#foundation) and [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/12/getting-started-with-swift-on-linux.html)

Comment: That's better than I thought. I have checked those places few weeks ago only to find that many classes were containing `NSUnimplemented()` calls.